# Where to find uniswap v3 ABI and swapExactTokensforTokens

Tags: uniswap

With the new version of uniswap (V3) I cannot find the router03 ABI on this page https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts
I am trying to find the equivalent of the function getAmountsOut in V3 abi.
Finally, for functions like swapExactTokensforTokens you don't have to mention gas. How so ? what happens when you use a function like this? If I want to increase speed I must use high gas so how do I include this in swapExactTokensforTokens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Uniswap V3,`swapExactTokensforTokens` can be found in `SwapRouter02`.

- `SwapRouter02` is deployed on `0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45`
- The ABI is available on Etherscan, see https://etherscan.io/address/0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45#code